# HP H240. does it do HW SATA RAID?

Tags: storage, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array, sata

I have some needs to get cheap HP 1U for very low end purposes.  I'm thinking about DL160 but I have no experience with the low end models.

Does the H240 "controller" works with SATA drives?  I would like to max it out with 4 LFF drives with 2x RAID1.  Does it support HW RAID1?

Thanks
W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll direct you to the [user manual](http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=7275272&docId=emr_na-c04441332&docLocale=en_US) and product guide.
https://www.hpe.com/h20195/v2/getpdf.aspx/c04346303.pdf

> The H240 Smart Host Bus Adapter provides flexibility to run in HBA
> mode or simple RAID mode. When operating in simple RAID mode, it
> provides RAID 0, RAID 1, and RAID 5 with optional HPE Secure
> Encryption capabilities. Unlike the HPE Smart Array Controllers, the
> H240 does not offer any acceleration or support cache modules.

The Smart Array H240 *is* compatible with SATA disks and it is capable of hardware RAID for the setup you're describing.

Comment: Thanks.  Sounds good. I have the P series every where, but I really need some low end HW RAID to make sure OS drive is mirrored (so no OS driver BS) with cheap SATA.  Even it is not accelerated, it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will support SATA and SAS drives. It doesn't *really* do hardware RAID, though. It uses a FakeRAID controller, which doesn't perform any kind of offload or battery backed caching. It also requires the use a specialized driver to maintain any RAID abstractions.

This essentially equates to all of the drawbacks of software RAID with all of the drawbacks of hardware RAID. I would *generally* advise to not use it, and use software RAID instead. Software RAID will have better metadata handling, better interfaces, and cross-system portability.

This controller will pass all of your drives directly through to the operating system, which in the case of a software RAID is what you want. This is true of both Windows and Linux, though the software RAID capabilities of Linux would be generally preferable.

So in summary, just teat it as a non-raid controller to avoid issues. OR if you need a hardware RAID controller use a higher end product, such as the H700 series.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with the above, this card seems to not even support both SAS and SATA, and when it is installed in a, for instance, Gen9 Server, from my understanding all the SATA RAID setup will rather be using the onboard B140i controller which will be using the Server's CPU AHCI / RAID controller.

The H240 would only really be used when SAS drives are added, or if a more complex RAID setup is required than what the B140i can handle.

Since the server I am speaking of on my side happens to be a DL180 Gen9, I would not suggest buying a HPe DL100 Gen9 Series to use with this controller, and I do not know if this is the case for the HPe DL300 Gen9 Series, but for the DL100 Series, since HPe was waiting for the Gen10 to do the full upgrades and make a fresh model, it seems they cut some corners on hopefully, only the lower series servers, which HPe installed a slight upgrade in the previous SAS cable which will only allow a max of 10G and not the 12G speeds the card should reach.

Hopefully this is also not the case for anyone else buying this Smart Array Card, since if that was the case, HPe advertising this card as a 12g card when they have used connectors and cables that would never reach these speeds, well, that would seem like legal cases against them from all directions.

So how I understand this SATA / SAS / Drive configuration, after reading more into the Intel Xeon CPU documentation, as well as the HPe documentation for how they implemented this, was, all SATA RAID that is not mixed, would use the already built in to the CPU SATA controller, this should allow less chance of the SAS Smart array and SAS cables from reaching their limit of under their advertised and sold speeds.

I will also add in, that when the client had purchased this server a few years ago, well they actually had purchased a HPe DL160 Gen9, which had constant SATA HDD errors from day 1, and after HPe came and replaced the backplane, the RAID Controller, and then 2 drives (out of 4) before the Motherboard, and they had asked the client to return the LIVE server so they could do diagnostic, etc.

I had to find and purchase a server to rent to this client, as well as move all their OS / DATA / etc. across, with as little further downtime as possible. I did all of this and HPe took this server, for over a month, and could not sort out these HDD errors that the server started with, and instead sent a new tested DL180 Gen9, with double of the CPU's although went from 1 x E5-2609v3 to 2 x E5-2603v3, they doubled the RAM, and replaced all the drives that had faults, as well as gave an extra 2 to setup the OS on, as they had done this offsite.

Fast forward a few years to today, so yes HPe supposedly "resolved" these issues on that server, and even replaced it with a bigger model with double of everything, but the client has now asked me to quote on upgrades, when I had supplied them that server it was the newer part numbers, and there had been v3 and v4 CPU choices, so the internals would have supported the upgrade, but on this DL180 Gen9 that is not the case, this is an earlier model number with a v1 Motherboard, and now would require a complete MB swap, RAM swap, and then the new v4 CPU's so pretty much an entire new server, as well as also then a BIOS / FW update yet the extended support plan ended about 8 months ago, so HPe won't even allow those, so the client pretty much has a piece of shhhhh now, which I can buy better refurbs than it for less than the upgrade cost.

Getting back to the H240, I would suggest reading up on the SFF cable specifications if you are looking at a 12G RAID card, since I do have a feeling that I have read that the cable used in the Gen9 Servers would not ever meet 12G speeds, and at most on a good day would be limited to around 10G or slightly less, which is a 1/3 of the "upgraded speed" that this card should have allowed. So if you are happy with possibly running slower than advertised it is probably by the looks of it a good, stable cheap card. If not, rather avoid.